# Update MS Access database using Oledb connection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-access, c#-3.0

When I was trying to update an MS Access database (`.mdb` file) using `OleDbConnection`, I got this error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine
>
> at   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at CostEstimate.Form1.processdbBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\Form1.cs :line 137

Line 137 refers to `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` in the below code

Please find the code below and help me in figuring out the problem

```
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"data source=C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\CE_Database.mdb;";

  conn.Open();

  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
  string[][] allData = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]

  foreach (string[] individualData in allData)
  {
    command.CommandText = @"insert into CETable(JobCode,JobName) Values(individualData[0],individualData[1])";
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

  conn.Close();
```

Comment: Does JET support incoming OLE-DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"data source=C:\Users\sy\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo\demo\CE_Database.mdb;";
conn.Open();
string[][] allData = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]

foreach (string[] individualData in allData)
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand()
    {
        Connection = conn,
        CommandText = string.Format(@"insert into CETable(JobCode,JobName) Values({0}, {1});", individualData[0], individualData[1])";
    };
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

But I'll also suggest that you set each field value through a parameter. This is a better practice to assure of not having injections